# UWP MediaPlayer получение метаданных из потока

Tags: c#, uwp, потоки-данных

В приложении UWP используется `Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer`, проинициализированный `Uri` ссылкой на интернет-радио. Это радио передаёт некоторые метаданные, например `Title`, которые отображаются, допустим, в каком-нибудь VLC плеере, но не отображаются в `SMTC` (шторке).

Похоже, что нужно считывать поток вручную, читать из него теги побайтовым чтением и потом присваивать поток и теги в плеер. Или есть более простые пути? Как это лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл библиотеку [UWPShoutcastMSS](https://github.com/Amrykid/UWPShoutcastMSS), которая неплохо справляется с поставленной задачей.

Использование библиотеки очень простое, наверное нет смысла описывать работу с ней подробно (тем более там в комплекте идёт проект с примером).

Единственное, о чём можно упомянуть, это то что в классе `MediaPlayer`, в отличие от `MediaElement`, в качестве `Source` используется `MediaSource`, а указанная выше библиотека возвращает `MediaStreamSource`.

Решается это очень просто:

```
player.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromMediaStreamSource(shoutcastStream.MediaStreamSource);
```